# Android bluetooth connection cannot be established on the first try

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, connection, ioexception

I'm trying to connect to a bluetooth device in my Android application but I have a problem.
It seems that I'm never able to connect to the bluetooth device on the first try.

I have the following code in the BluetoothConnectThread:

```
public class BluetoothConnectThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private Context context;
    private BluetoothManager manager;

    public BluetoothConnectThread(BluetoothDevice mmDevice, UUID uuid, Context context, BluetoothManager manager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.mmDevice = mmDevice;
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Try to connect");
            mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(mmDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (Exception connectException) {
            connectException.printStackTrace();
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
                System.out.println("Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection! (1)");
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                closeException.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection! (2)");
            }

            try {
                System.out.println("Try to connect again");
                mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(mmDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (Exception connectException2) {
                connectException.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    System.out.println("Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection! (3)");
                } catch (IOException closeException) {
                    closeException.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection! (4)");
                }
            }
        }

        if(mmSocket.isConnected()) {
            if(mmSocket.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("Connected");
    //Do something with the connected socket
```

I receive the following log when calling the run method:

```
07-12 14:17:10.906 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test I/System.out: Try to connect
07-12 14:17:10.910 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
07-12 14:17:13.025 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
07-12 14:17:13.025 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:573)
07-12 14:17:13.025 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:550)
07-12 14:17:13.025 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:325)
07-12 14:17:13.025 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at com.example.niekdewit.test.BluetoothConnectThread.run(BluetoothConnectThread.java:33)
07-12 14:17:13.025 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test I/System.out: Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection! (1)
07-12 14:17:13.025 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test I/System.out: Try to connect again
07-12 14:17:13.025 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
07-12 14:17:13.147 9941-9941/com.example.niekdewit.test I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2e01eda7 time:762005544
07-12 14:17:16.503 9941-9941/com.example.niekdewit.test I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2e01eda7 time:762008901
07-12 14:17:17.279 9941-10518/com.example.niekdewit.test I/System.out: Connected
```

I tried replacing the 2 lines

```
mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(mmDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

with

```
 mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
```

But that doesn't work either, it generates a different log though. Using this method I'm also not able to connect on the second try.

```
07-12 14:27:15.968 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test I/System.out: Try to connect
07-12 14:27:15.969 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
07-12 14:27:18.205 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
07-12 14:27:18.205 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:573)
07-12 14:27:18.205 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:550)
07-12 14:27:18.205 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:325)
07-12 14:27:18.205 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at com.example.niekdewit.test.BluetoothConnectThread.run(BluetoothConnectThread.java:36)
07-12 14:27:18.205 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test I/System.out: Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection! (1)
07-12 14:27:18.206 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test I/System.out: Try to connect again
07-12 14:27:18.206 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
07-12 14:27:18.319 15135-15135/com.example.niekdewit.test I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2e01eda7 time:762610717
07-12 14:27:20.669 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
07-12 14:27:20.669 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:573)
07-12 14:27:20.669 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:550)
07-12 14:27:20.669 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:325)
07-12 14:27:20.669 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test W/System.err:     at com.example.niekdewit.test.BluetoothConnectThread.run(BluetoothConnectThread.java:36)
07-12 14:27:20.669 15135-15622/com.example.niekdewit.test I/System.out: Couldn't establish Bluetooth connection! (3)
07-12 14:27:20.854 15135-15135/com.example.niekdewit.test I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2e01eda7 time:762613252
```

When I first try to connect with this line

```
 mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
```

And try on the second try ("try to connect again") with this line

```
mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(mmDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Then it generates the same log as the first log I attached

I have no idea what is going on?
I hope one of you can see what is wrong with my code, or point me in the right direction.

EDIT:
When the device is already paired then its possible to connect on the first try using both methods.

EDIT2:

```
mmSocket = mmDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
```

Also does not work

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change

```
mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(mmDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

to this

```
    // BluetoothDevice device= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice("00:1C:4D:02:A6:55");
    // You already have a device so capture the method then invoke a socket
    Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
    socket = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));
    socket.connect();
    // Do some cool stuff
```

This is how I always connect to devices

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this did not fix my problem. The output log is the same as my first log that I attached to my post :(

Comment: You have a Bluetooth manager defined, but you don't use it. I might take a look at that since you get an error of `W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback`

Comment: Bluetooth manager is a class I wrote myself which acts as an interface for the activity to make a bluetooth connection etc.

I use this in the thread class to tell the manager a connection has been made:

Comment: if(mmSocket.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Connected");

            // Get a handler that can be used to post to the main thread
            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

            Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    manager.ConnectionEstablishedEvent(mmSocket);
                }
            };
            mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
        }

(this is a new comment because of the character limit)

Comment: I haven't touched android in years, so maybe someone else on SO can help. I would take a look at the docs again though. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html